# Matrix operator to stack the rows of a matrix on the "diagonal"

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am looking for a matrix operator (or a mathematical expression) that does the following:

I have a matrix A of dimension 3 by 5:

```
a_11 a_12 a_13 a_14 a_15
a_21 a_22 a_23 a_24 a_25
a_31 a_32 a_33 a_34 a_35
```

I want to obtain the matrix 3 by 15:

```
a_11 a_12 a_13 a_14 a_15 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    a_21 a_22 a_23 a_24 a_25 0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    a_31 a_32 a_33 a_34 a_35
```

I have tried to use Kronecker products but I didn't arrive to any solution.

Comment: What do you ,Ean by operator? I do not think there is one. But you could write a quick function to do that

Comment: Yes I am looking for a mathematical expression to write the transformation from matrix A to B. Basically I need matrix algebra.  As for coding in MATLAB, I could write a function without any problem. Thanks

Comment: What for? Does it relate to solving any data problem? If yes, tell us what is the problem. If it is a pure matrix algebra question, it suits better the mathematics Q&A.

Comment: Also it's trivial to do without any matrix algebra, if this is applied problem.

Comment: Yes, basically I have a linear regression model. A is a design matrix $T \times K$ (where T is time and K is the number of regressors), and I want to write it as as the above $T \times TK$ matrix since I have time varying coefficients in my linear regression.

Comment: In practice I have $    \underbrace{\boldsymbol{Y}}_{\text{$T \times 1$}} = \underbrace{\boldsymbol{B}}_{\text{$T \times TQ$}} \underbrace{\tilde{\boldsymbol{\Phi}}}_{\text{$TQ \times 1$}} + \underbrace{\boldsymbol{U}}_{\text{$T \times 1$}} \hspace{3cm} $

Comment: If you're looking for a matrix operation that has a specific name that you can express it as a  [penetrating face product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#The_penetrating_face_product). Not clear however how this helps your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it using the following:

```
a = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
sz = size(a) % find the dimensions
m = zeros(sz(1), prod(sz)) %Create a matrix of zeros
for row = 1:sz(1)
    m(row,(1:sz(2)) + (row-1) * sz(2)) = a(row,:) %replace each row accordingly
end

m =

     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     4     5     6     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     7     8     9
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @pppery this was a question asked on stackexchange/cross validated. You can edit it as it seems fit.

Comment: I know. It's now on Stack Overflow, and thus "This is a programing question rather than algebra", which I edited out, is useless fluff. The point of my previous comment is that we prefer to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3750257) here rather than simply tossing people fish.

Answer (score 0):

Not a matrix-algebra expression, but in case it helps: this can be easily done using [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to split the matrix into a cell array of its rows, and passing a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-4) of those rows to [`blkdiag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html):

```
A = randi(9,3,5); % example input
A_cell = num2cell(A, 2);
result = blkdiag(A_cell{:});
```